# .htaccess multiple url variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to write .htaccess to show url with common patters
for example

```
1: abc.com/mypage   --> works fine 
2: abc.com/mypage/page/1  --> works fine 
3: abc.com/mypage/category/2   --> works fine 
4: abc.com/mypage/page/1/category/2   --> not works fine
```

so below is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteRule mypage/page/([^/]*) /?p=main_page&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule mypage/category/([^/]*) /?p=main_page&cid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule mypage/page/([^/]*)/category/([^/]*) /?p=main_page&page=$1&cid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule mypage /?p=main_page [L]
```

how can we fix it please guide way to fix it

Comment: Change `mypage/page/([^/]*)/categroy/([^/]*)` to `mypage/page/([^/]*)/category/([^/]*)` (miss typed `category`)

Comment: no bro that is not issue , i fixed typos in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo but more importantly you are missing anchors in your regex. You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^mypage/page/([^/]+)/?$ ?p=main_page&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mypage/categroy/([^/]+)/?$ ?p=main_page&cid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mypage/page/([^/]+)/category/([^/]+)/?$ ?p=main_page&page=$1&cid=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mypage/?$ ?p=main_page [L,QSA]
```

Comment: is that [L,QSA] was missing

Comment: `QSA` is query string append. Did this answer work out?